# JPA native query second level cache

Tags: jpa

I need to use second level cache for native sql using JPA. 
I am not finding the way to do it. If JPA supports native query cache, can someone suggest the way

Comment: I've posted some sample configuration for the ehcache cache provider, I wrote a blg post about pitfalls of second level cache that might help as well, have a look http://blog.jhades.org/setup-and-gotchas-of-the-hibernate-second-level-and-query-caches/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JPA L2 cache is designed for Entities. If you haven't got any then firstly, it is pointless using JPA, and secondly, even if you do have Entities a native query does not necessarily return them, so nothing is cacheable.

Obviously you may find an implementation that will allow an amount of caching of information in the L2 cache from native (SQL) queries, BUT then you are not using the JPA specification standard, and instead using vendor specifics (which would stop working if you ever changed JPA provider)

Answer (score 0):

JPA supports second level cache using the `@Cacheable` annotation, see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkjio.html) the official documentation. The configuration of the second level cache is persistence provider specific, this is an example of how to set it up hibernate.

First add the integration with the cache provider, in this case ehcache:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
    <version>SOME-HIBERNATE-VERSION</version>
</dependency>
```

Then add this to the session factory configuration:

```
<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
<prop key="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">/your-cache-config.xml</prop>
```

Then add a ehcache xml configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             updateCheck="false"
       xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd" name="yourCacheManager">

     <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>

     <cache name="yourEntityCache"
            maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000"
            eternal="false"
            overflowToDisk="false"
            timeToLiveSeconds="86400" />

     <cache name="org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache"
            maxElementsInMemory="10000"
            eternal="false
            timeToLiveSeconds="86400"
            overflowToDisk="false"
            memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" />

  <defaultCache
          maxElementsInMemory="10000"
          eternal="false"
          timeToLiveSeconds="86400"
          overflowToDisk="false"
          memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" />
</ehcache>
```

The cache should be ready to work, try to annotate an entity with `@Cache` (native Hibernate annotation) or the standard `@Cacheable` JPA annotation. Queries need to be marked as cached separatelly.

This is how to cache a named query:

```
@NamedQuery(name="account.queryName",
   query="select acct from Account ...",
   hints={
       @QueryHint(name="org.hibernate.cacheable",
       value="true")
   }     
})
```

and this is how to cache a criteria query:

```
List cats = session.createCriteria(Cat.class)
    .setCacheable(true)
    .list();
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I am not having entities and don't want to create also. We have already done with native queries, so now we want to add second level cache for that.